# How to calculate the price after trade on Uniswap?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, uniswap

I would like to get the price of a token after a swap. For example the price is now $1, and I would like to see how much will be the price after my swap. Is the execution price what I need in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Let's use this transaction as an example:

https://bscscan.com/tx/0xdd38b435d9840062db9106e23712873fa2da44c366fa737b17f7fc6d111ef076#eventlog

Here `172054109197` Zombie tokens were transferred to [Zombie / BUSD LP](https://bscscan.com/address/0x5ba1731c5170afd84dbc8ea78ec1566500930d87) in exchange for `6357581284196624466` BUSD tokens.

Here is the Swap event:

```
amount0In: 172054109197
amount1In: 0
amount0Out: 0
amount1Out: 6357581284196624466
```

If we look at both ([Zombie](https://bscscan.com/address/0xde7c6452072a4bd77a6633969bdf579f8644f111#readContract), [BUSD](https://bscscan.com/address/0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56#readContract)) contracts, they both use 18 `decimals`, i.e. we can think of these values as:

`0.000000172` Zombie traded for `6.3575` BUSD

To understand the price impact, we need to look at the [Zombie / BUSD LP](https://bscscan.com/address/0x5ba1731c5170afd84dbc8ea78ec1566500930d87) reserves before and after the transaction.

Before:

```
reserve0: 1203765031
reserve1: 6402195517789394391
```

After:

```
reserve0: 173257874228
reserve1: 44614233592769925
```

We know (by looking at the LP contract) that `reserve0` represents **Zombie** token and `reserve1` represents **BUSD** token.

As we traded Zombie for BUSD, we have to add the amount being traded in to the first reserve and deduct the amount being traded for from the second reserve, i.e.

```
reserve0: 1203765031+172054109197=173257874228
reserve1: 6402195517789394391+6357581284196624466=44614233592769925
```

This is how the Swap affected the reserves and therefore the price ratio.